# PHP/PDO taking select taking longer than CLI or MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch, fetchall

I have a windows production server running IIS7 and PHP 7.2 connecting to a Linux db server.
When I make the query "select * from posts" on the production server from the CLI or inside MySQL Workbench it returns all results in an average of 0.25 seconds or less.

When I use a PDO db call in my PHP application I get varied results, but always ranging in the 7 sec. to 30 second rage. As you could imagine, this makes for unacceptable webpage loading times.

The select * statement is only returning 4500 rows. I have searched Stack Overflow and most questions like this are referencing complicated queries with many joins and where cases... but this is  just a simple select *.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to actually show your code.

Comment: lets start with something simple, why would you need 4500 rows at once?

Comment: Could be caused by the number of entries returned, try query ```select * from posts limit 4500``` in MySQL Workbench.